# Merging two data frames in R (Vlookup)

Tags: r

I am trying to comine two data frames such that I match the values in the vector called `vec` by their index number.

```
vec=c(-2,-5)

y=as.data.frame(cbind(0:(length(c(vec))-1)*2+1,c(vec)))

  V1 V2
1  1 -2
2  3 -5

x=as.data.frame(1:4,names="V1"); names(x)="V1"

  V1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

What I want is a dataframe to look like this

```
  V1  V2
1  1  -2
2  2  NA
3  3  -5
4  4  NA
```

I have trying to get this command to work but as of no luck

```
merge(x,y,by.x="V1")
```

Comment: You just want a left join: `merge(x, y, all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks Mr.Flick though I wish you had kept my example up. The answer you suggested in another post was alot more complicated. This was just a much simpler answer with your beauitful simple answer.

Comment: I just think It's a simple question with a simple answer and I know many R users are looking for this quick answer rather than along one. My question was similar to how someone who is used to Vlookup in excel is thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Try a left_join()

```
z <- left_join(x, y, by="V1")
print(z)
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2
1  1 -2
2  2 NA
3  3 -5
4  4 NA
```

Comment: Thanks Reeza. I would appreciate if you could vote to reopen. I think this is a simple question with a simple example and answer that many R users want.